# Get Element Attribute in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

hi how to use Get Element Attribute in Robot framework? in instruction I have 
Return value of element attribute.

attribute_locator consists of element locator followed by an @ sign and attribute name, for example `element_id@class`.

I have this `xpath=${check_radio_xpath}@class` is this right way?
where `${check_radio_xpath} =  md-radio-11`

I get this error:

```
${ischecked} = Selenium2Library . Get Element Attribute xpath=${check_radio_xpath}@class

Documentation:
Return value of element attribute.

TRACE   Arguments: [ 'xpath=md-radio-11@class' ]        
DEBUG   Finished Request    
FAIL    ValueError: Element 'xpath=md-radio-11' not found.
```

Comment: Please edit the question and format it.

Answer (score 8):

I think you're pretty close.  Please try to format your question better, I took a quick shot because your question is difficult to read.  The result will be more and better help from the community

```
${RADIO_XPATH}    //*[@id="${check_radio_xpath}"]
${CLASS}=    Selenium2Library.Get Element Attribute    ${check_radio_xpath}@class
```

Comment: so this was your problem and it solved it or you solved it by other means?  If my answer is correct, please accept it.  If you solved it a different way, please answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

sample for this `<div><label for="foo"></label></div>`

```
${for_value}=   Get Element Attribute  xpath=//div/label  for
Log To Console  ${for_value}
```

console result is:

> foo

Answer (score 1):

This snippet works for me :

```
Get Line Numbers And Verify
    ${line_number1}=    Get Element Attribute   //*[@id="file-keywords-txt-L1"] data-line-number
    Log To Console  ${line_number1}
    ${line_number2}=    Get Element Attribute   //*[@id="file-keywords-txt-L2"] data-line-number
    Log To Console  ${line_number2}
    Verify in order of ${line_number1} and ${line_number2} is true
```

What was important is that the spaces/tabs between the keywords are correct, otherwise it does not get recognised as a so called keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, i wanted to check meta noindex content in page source.

i used this.

```
${content}  Get Element Attribute   xpath=//meta[@name="robots"]@content
should be equal as strings  ${content}  noindex,follow
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use both XPath and CSS selector if you have selenium library

```
${title}=  Get Element Attribute  ${xpath}    attribute=title
```